# I've created a variable based on a pattern. How can I rank the occurrence of that pattern that I've flagged?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

In the mock data set below, I've created 'nonres_flag' as an indicator of each time a person becomes a non-resident (i.e., 'res' changes from '1' to '0').

Now I need to create a ranking variable ('rank_nonres_flag') for 'nonres_flag'. This new column, 'rank_nonres_flag', should provide the ranking of the occurrence of the nonres_flag. I need to know if this is the first time they became a nonresident, or the second time, or the nth time.

For example, person 3 has two nonres_flag instances. For the first time person 3 has a nonres_flag=1, I need rank_nonres_flag to equal '1' for the first 2 time periods when person 3 has 'res' = 0 after 'res' = 1. This will indicate that this is the first time that person 3 has had a period where 'res'=0.

Similarly, for the second time person 3 has a nonres_flag=1, I need rank_nonres_flag='2' for the second time period (it's only one time period) that person 3 has 'res'=0 after 'res'=1.

The solution will need to apply to an unlimited number of nonres_flag instances per person.

Thanks for your help!

```r
#Load packages
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Create data set
person <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
time <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
res <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)

#Populate data frame
d <- cbind(person, time, res)
d <- as.data.frame(d)

d %>% 
#Data are longitudinal, so I'll group by person
  group_by(person) %>% 
#First, I create an indicator variable to mark each time a person changes from 'res'=1 to 'res'=0
  mutate(nonres_flag = if_else(Lag(res) == 1 & res == 0, 1, 0, 0)) %>%
#Second, here is where I need help ranking each time this change happens within a person
  mutate(rank_nonres_flag = rank(nonres_flag)) 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   person [3]
#>    person  time   res nonres_flag rank_nonres_flag
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1      1     1     1           0              1.5
#>  2      1     2     0           1              3  
#>  3      1     3     1           0              1.5
#>  4      2     1     1           0              1  
#>  5      3     1     1           0              2.5
#>  6      3     2     0           1              5.5
#>  7      3     3     0           0              2.5
#>  8      3     4     1           0              2.5
#>  9      3     5     0           1              5.5
#> 10      3     6     1           0              2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: May you elaborate more about the expected outcome?

Comment: why `Lag` instead of `lag`?  Why four arguments used in `if_else`?

Comment: Can you please calculate the expected outcome manually for the example and include it in question?

Comment: Thanks, @SinhNguyen. I've edited the question to be clearer about the expected outcome.

Comment: Thanks, @AnilGoyal. Lag and lag should do the same thing here. And I've used 4 arguments to tell R that I want nonres_flag=0 if the output of lag is missing.  
if_else(condition, true, false, missing = NULL)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Borrowing @RonakShah's idea to use the cumsum() function, I used it in an if_else() to provide the cumulative sum of the flag variable for each value of res=0. This works especially well because the logic based on the flag ensures that no 'res'=0 could be assigned a cumsum() if it does not have a flag (indicating that it's a non-residence time period that was preceded by a res=1 time period). Thanks, all!

```r
#Load packages
library(Hmisc)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:Hmisc':
#> 
#>     src, summarize
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

#Create data set
person <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
time <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
res <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)

#Populate data frame
d <- cbind(person, time, res)
d <- as.data.frame(d)

d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(nonres_flag = if_else(Lag(res) == 1 & res == 0, 1, 0, 0)) %>%
  mutate(rank_nonres_flag = if_else(res == 0, cumsum(nonres_flag), 0, 0))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   person [3]
#>    person  time   res nonres_flag rank_nonres_flag
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1      1     1     1           0                0
#>  2      1     2     0           1                1
#>  3      1     3     1           0                0
#>  4      2     1     1           0                0
#>  5      3     1     1           0                0
#>  6      3     2     0           1                1
#>  7      3     3     0           0                1
#>  8      3     4     1           0                0
#>  9      3     5     0           1                2
#> 10      3     6     1           0                0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(nonres_flag = as.integer(lag(res) == 1 & res == 0), 
         rank_nonres_flag = cumsum(nonres_flag)) %>%
  ungroup

#   person  time   res nonres_flag rank_nonres_flag
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <int>            <int>
# 1      1     1     1           0                0
# 2      1     2     0           1                1
# 3      1     3     1           0                1
# 4      2     1     1           0                0
# 5      3     1     1           0                0
# 6      3     2     0           1                1
# 7      3     3     0           0                1
# 8      3     4     1           0                1
# 9      3     5     0           1                2
#10      3     6     1           0                2
```

Comment: thanks! This is almost it. In the 'rank_nonres_flag' column, I need the rank to only occur in the rows where 'res' = 0 (after 'res'=1, per the pattern created by my 'nonres_flag'. I'm not sure if cumsum() can do that? Ideas appreciated!

Comment: ...actually, I just ran your code and for some reason do not get the same output.

Comment: @ryorlets Please can you edit your post to show your actual expected output in a table format? You must have `plyr` loaded in your environment hence you don't get the same output. Try using `dplyr::mutate`.